# why facebook connect always calls back to localhost even when URL updated in FB settings

Tags: facebook

why facebook connect always calls back to localhost URL  even when the URL was updated in FB settings.

I have updated application key+secret key  to point to another application that has no more LOCALHOST configured as CONNECT URL. Still my web page opens Facebook POPUP with localhost URL when clicking blue f connect button.

I am using FBToolkit.Samples.Connect.Web

Answer (score 2):

It needs 15 -20 mins to reflect updated application settings on facebook.